# Send arguments and file with Ajax to NodeJs

Tags: javascript, ajax, express, post

I have a problem with my code and I don't see where is the problem.

I have this AJAX part which take a file from a form and an argument and send it to my nodejs server :

```
var layerID = 2;
var formData = new FormData($("#formid")[0]);
formData.append('layer', layerID);
  $.ajax({
     url: "http://localhost:3000/file-upload",
     type: 'POST',
     data: formData,
     cache: false,
     contentType: false,
     processData: false
  });
```

and i have this part with express which is supposed to receive the file and the argument:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
   extended: false
}))

app.post('/file-upload', function (req, res) {
  console.log('params: ' + req.params);
    console.log('body: ' + req.body);
    console.log('query: ' + req.query);
  upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      errorHandler
      return
    } else {
      successHandler
    }
  })
})
```

My problem is that I correctly receive the file but I don't receive the argument 'layer' in my nodejs server.

Answer (score 1):

You are POSTing multipart data, but you only have a body parser for `urlencoded` data.

See the documentation for [body parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser):

> This does not handle multipart bodies, due to their complex and
>   typically large nature. For multipart bodies, you may be interested in
>   the following modules:
>
> - busboy and connect-busboy
> - multiparty and connect-multiparty
> - formidable
> - multer

Comment: The upload part is the usage of multer.
var upload = multer({storage: storage]).single('photo')
in storage i declare the destination and the filename with multer.diskStorage.

Answer (score 1):

You can use packages like `multiparty` for parsing multipart data in following way. There are other packages as well.

#### Backend Code

```
const multiparty = require('multiparty');

         // Define POST route
 app.post('/file-upload', function (req, res) {
     const form = new multiparty.Form();

     form.parse(request, async (error, fields, files) => {
       if (error) throw new Error(error);

       try {
         const path = files.file[0].path;
         const layer = fields && fields.layer && fields.layer[0]
         const buffer = fs.readFileSync(path);

         // TODO 

         return response.status(200).send(data);
       } catch (error) {
         return response.status(400).send(error);
       }
     });
 }
```

You can use it this way. You can read from fields.

#### Client Code

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', fileObj);

uploadHandler(formData) // this function will make an API call
```

Now you will be able to get `files.file[0]`

Comment: I tried your code and now it says that files.file[0] is undefined, do i have to send the picture in a new way with multiparty ?

Comment: No, I'll update answer to have client code as well. BTW, can you check ``files`` object once?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, the solution was to simply move my log of req.body in the upload function and call it like that: console.log("layer: " + req.body['layer']);